# How to use TYPO3 Link wizard in extension

Tags: typo3

In an extension, I would like to be able to modify an existing link. The corresponding field in the database is one which may contain several links (e.g. tt_content.bodytext).

I want to reuse as much already existing functionality as possible. So I would like to use the already existing link wizard.

What I did find was the existing route `rteckeditor_wizard_browse_links` which uses [rte_ckeditor/Classes/Controller/BrowseLinksController.php](https://github.com/TYPO3/TYPO3.CMS/blob/53cd95c8cca552bc44a8f40434cbb58017e5ad64/typo3/sysext/rte_ckeditor/Classes/Controller/BrowseLinksController.php).

I use this in my view helper:

```php
 $parameters = [
   'table'     => $table,
   'fieldName' => $field,
   'pid'       => $pid,
   'uid'       => $uid,
   'recordType' => $recordType;
 ];
 $urlParameters = [
   'contentsLanguage' => 'en',
   // 'route'
   // 'token*
  'P' => $parameters,
  'curUrl' => [
    'url' => $url
    // todo: add anchor text etc. ...
  ],
  'editorId' => 'cke_1'
];
$route = 'rteckeditor_wizard_browse_links';
return (string)$uriBuilder->buildUriFromRoute($route, $urlParameters);
```

This does opens the link wizard correctly. But it is intertwined with the ckeditor.

When I press "Set link" nothing happens and I get the following JavaScript error (visible if Console is open in Browser):

```
RteLinkBrowser.js?bust=8d6016d70f0f490d5e7d24262f0ec96230f399d9:77 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'document' of null
    at Object.LinkBrowser.finalizeFunction (RteLinkBrowser.js?bust=8d6016d70f0f490d5e7d24262f0ec96230f399d9:77)
    at HTMLFormElement.UrlLinkHandler.link (UrlLinkHandler.js?bust=8d6016d70f0f490d5e7d24262f0ec96230f399d9:40)
    at HTMLFormElement.dispatch (jquery.min-16985e7a97b69d2a9c29e484ac3b581a.js:2)
    at HTMLFormElement.y.handle (jquery.min-16985e7a97b69d2a9c29e484ac3b581a.js:2)
LinkBrowser.finalizeFunction @ RteLinkBrowser.js?bust=8d6016d70f0f490d5e7d24262f0ec96230f399d9:77
UrlLinkHandler.link @ UrlLinkHandler.js?bust=8d6016d70f0f490d5e7d24262f0ec96230f399d9:40
dispatch @ jquery.min-16985e7a97b69d2a9c29e484ac3b581a.js:2
y.handle @ jquery.min-16985e7a97b69d2a9c29e484ac3b581a.js:2
```

The corresponding line in [RteLinkBrowser.js](https://github.com/TYPO3/TYPO3.CMS/blob/53cd95c8cca552bc44a8f40434cbb58017e5ad64/typo3/sysext/rte_ckeditor/Resources/Public/JavaScript/RteLinkBrowser.js#L77) is:

```
var linkElement = RteLinkBrowser.CKEditor.document.createElement('a');
```

The Link Wizard expects the ckeditor window to be open and uses things in the DOM that are not there.

Is there some way to directly open the link wizard for a specific link within a text field?

Or alternatively open the text field with ckeditor and have the specific link preselected.

Answer (score 1):

*I don't have an answer, but at least here is a work-around / alternative:*

### Don't open Link wizard directly, open field in editor

As an alternative, consider not using the link wizard but using the route 'record_edit' to open the edit dialog for a specific RTE field. If you double-click on a link in that, the link wizard will open.

The following example was taken from linkvalidator in the core and modified. It opens an editor dialog for the field tt_content.bodytext for the record with uid $uid.

```
$requestUri = GeneralUtility::getIndpEnv('REQUEST_URI') .
    '&id=' . $pageid;

$uriBuilder = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(\TYPO3\CMS\Backend\Routing\UriBuilder::class);
$url = (string)$uriBuilder->buildUriFromRoute('record_edit', [
    'edit' => [
        'tt_content' => [
            $uid => 'edit'
        ]
    ],
    'columnsOnly' => 'bodytext',
    'returnUrl' => $requestUri
]);
```

[image]

**Update:** For TYPO3 9, a ViewHelper exists for opening the field with FormEngine in the Backend. This has the same result.

https://docs.typo3.org/other/typo3/view-helper-reference/9.5/en-us/typo3/backend/latest/Link/EditRecord.html